# Google App Engine fail to upload: can't start thread

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to upload my data in a local server.

I used the command line:

```
--url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api/ --filename=C:\Users\Brayan\Desktop\sns.csv upload_data
```

My base is huge and the upload runs fine for a while, then it breaks:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 143, in _loop_forever
    self._select()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 165, in _select
    fd_to_callback[fd]()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1944, in tick
    self.requests.put(conn)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 92, in put
    _THREAD_POOL.submit(self._handle, obj)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\thread_executor.py", line 60, in submit
    t.start()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 745, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
error: can't start new thread
```

Somebody knows what happened?

Comment: How huge is your data?  And how much RAM do you have?  I can only guess, but I suspect you're running out of RAM.

Comment: A .csv file of 178MB.
How can i get more memory to the local Gae?

Comment: Did you check your computer's memory usage as you're uploading?  If you're running out of RAM, you could increase your swap file size.

Comment: I did it, didn't work... =(